# Why is $P(X_{t+1} \mid e_{1:t}, e_{t+1}) = \alpha P(e_{t+1} \mid X_{t+1}, e_{1:t}) P(X_{t+1} \mid e_{1:t})$ true in Norvig & Russell's book?

Tags: norvig-russell, bayes-theorem

On page 572 of Norvig & Russell's AI book (edition 3)

[image: Bayes rule filtering]

Going from the first line to the second line in one shot like that, I am lost.

Can someone walk me through it step by step?

I tried but got:

$$
\frac{P(X_{t+1}) * P(e_{1:t} | X_{t+1}) * P(e_{t+1} | X_{t+1}) }{P(e_{1:t}, e_{t+1})}
$$

and then do not know how to turn it into that second line that says (using Bayes's rule)

Comment: You can use mathjax to format the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me denote the events with simpler symbols

- $A = X_{t+1}$
- $C = e_{1:t} = e_1, \dots e_t$
- $D = e_{t+1}$

So, we can rewrite

$$
P(X_{t+1} \mid e_{1:t}, e_{t+1}) = \alpha P(e_{t+1} \mid X_{t+1},  e_{1:t}) P(X_{t+1} \mid  e_{1:t})\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

as follows

$$
P(A \mid C, D) = \alpha P(D \mid A,  C) P(A \mid  C)
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Now, note that $C, D$ is a shorthand for $C \cap D = B$, so $P(A \mid C, D) = P(A \mid B)$.

So, by the Bayes rule, we have

\begin{align}
P(A \mid B) 
&= \frac{P(B \mid A) P(A) }{P(B)} \\
&= \frac{\color{red}{P(C, D \mid A)} P(A) }{P(C, D)}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

Let's expand the red term

\begin{align}
\color{red}{P(C, D \mid A)}  
&= P(B \mid A) \\
&= \frac{P(B, A) }{P(A)}\\
&= \color{blue}{\frac{P(C, D, A) }{P(A)}}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}

Now, let $E = C, A = C \cap A$. So, let's continue writing \ref{4}

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{P(C, D, A) }{P(A)}}
&=\frac{P(D, E) }{P(A)} \\
&= \frac{P(D \mid E) P(E) }{P(A)} \\
&= \frac{P(D \mid C, A) P(C, A) }{P(A)} \\
&= \color{green}{\frac{P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) P(C) }{P(A)}}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}
Let's put \ref{5} back into \ref{3}

\begin{align}
P(A \mid B) 
&= \frac{\color{green}{\frac{P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) P(C) }{P(A)}} P(A) }{P(C, D)} \\
&= \frac{ P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) P(C) }{P(C, D)} \\
&= \frac{ P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) P(C) }{P(D \mid C) P(C)} \\
&= \frac{ P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) }{P(D \mid C)} \\
&= \frac{1}{P(D \mid C)} P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C) \\
&= \alpha P(D \mid C, A) P(A \mid C)
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

Comment: I got lost at that line, let A = C and A after (4).

Comment: @mLstudent33 It's let $E = C, A$. But $C, A$ is a shorthand for $C \cap A$ (i.e. the intersection of C and A, so I am denoting $C \cap A$ by $E$ in order to apply the regular definition of joint and conditional probabilities. Note that events are sets. I've edited the answer to add another step that clarifies what I did.

Comment: Thanks but I still do not see how 5 can be substituted for P(B | A).  Oops I see it now

Comment: P(C,D | A) is P(C,D | A) :)

Comment: Are you returning back or the question is impressive enough?

Comment: @hanugm I've restarted to answer questions every once in a while. I answer the ones that I either can answer quickly or I like. This was one that I liked because it was about the Bayes rule ;)